# Export large datatable to excel 2003 by c# without excel COM

Tags: c#, excel, datatable, dataset

I have a datatable with larger than 300.000 row, i want export this datatable to excel 2003 but don't use Excel COM. I have used NPOI but it raise error OutOfMemory. I'm finding a thirt party component (free) can export for each row and write directly to file to avoid out of memory. Who can help me? thanks.

Comment: I take it using a CSV file is out of the question?

Comment: Note that each Excel 2003 sheet has a limit of 65536 rows.

Answer (score 1):

How about a csv file ? It is readable from Excel.

Answer (score 0):

Try this Libs. I am not sure about the capacity

1. http://ehl.codeplex.com/
2. http://excelexportlib.codeplex.com/

Answer (score 0):

You can export to an excel-file with the use of a webgrid (only in code). Under the assumption that you're creating a WinForm-application, you will have to make a reference to the `System.Web` library.

```
// Create the DataGrid and perform the databinding
var myDataGrid = new System.Web.UI.WebControls.DataGrid();
myDataGrid.HeaderStyle.Font.Bold = true;
myDataGrid.DataSource = myDataTable;
myDataGrid.DataBind();
string myFile = "put the name here with full path.xls"
var myFileStream = new FileStream( myFile, FileMode.Create, FileAccess.ReadWrite );
// Render the DataGrid control to a file
using ( var myStreamWriter = new StreamWriter( myFileStream ) )
{     
    using (var myHtmlTextWriter = new System.Web.UI.HtmlTextWriter(myStreamWriter ))         
    {         
        myDataGrid .RenderControl( myHtmlTextWriter );     
    } 
}
```

I haven't tested it with so many records, so I don't know the impact of this memory-wise.

**Edit:**

Take note of the comment of @Charles Williams that excel 2003 has a row limitation